# Javascript / PHP show id or name object

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id='test1' name='test1'class=default></td>
        <td id='test2' name='test2'class=default></td>
        <td id='test3' name='test3'class=default></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and function:

```
function pop() {
 alert("test")
}
```

When I click a `<td>` the popup appears with the word "test".
But, is it possible to show in this popup the ID or the Name from this `<td>`? I already tried with the `get_class` but that didn't work.

Comment: Java **is not** JavaScript.

Comment: Are u using the php manual to try javascript functions?

Comment: Why is this tagged in PHP?

Answer (score 3):

***JavaScript :***

```
function pop(el) {
   alert(el.getAttribute("id")) /* instead of 'id' you can pass 'name' attribute */
}

window.onload = function(){
   var elements=document.querySelectorAll('table tr td.default')
   for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){ 
      var onc = function(x){return function(){ pop(x)}}(elements[i])
      elements[i].addEventListener('click',onc , false);
   }
}
```

#### [CodeOpen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KDmqc)

Comment: Notulysses your answer works perfectly, the problem is that it's an event... I'm doing the follow:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

And I want do when the event start spawn the current id/name object and when event finish spawn the new id/name...

I don't know if it's possible.

Sorry, I can't explain better xD

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to your question.You should remove the class because it was redandunt to the ID

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id='test1' name="test1" onClick="pop()"></td>
        <td id='test2' name="test2" onClick="pop()"></td>
        <td id='test3' name="test3" onClick="pop()"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This the Javascript

```
<script>
function pop() 
{
   alert("test");
}  
</script>
```

I Think this could help you totally.